# Finding a unitary operator on L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2},dxdy)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, noncommutative-geometry, quantum-mechanics, gauge-theory

I have a one parameter (r) family of self-adjoint representations of the universal enveloping algebra of some nilpotent Lie group on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2},dxdy)$ as follows:
$$\hat{X}^{r}=\hat{x}-i(r-1)\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\\
\hat{Y}^{r}=\hat{y}-ir\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\\
\hat{p}_{x}=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\\
\hat{p}_{y}=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.$$

The nonvanishing Lie brackets between the respective vector fields read:
$$[\hat{X}^{r},\hat{Y}^{r}]=i\theta\hat{I},\hspace{.5in}[\hat{X}^{r},\hat{p}_{x}]=[\hat{Y}^{r},\hat{p}_{y}]=i\hbar\hat{I}.$$ Here, $\hat{I}$ is the identity operator on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2},dxdy)$. I call the parameter (r) gauge parameter as it disappears on the right side of the commutators.

Now I want to find a unitary operator on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2},dxdy)$ explicitly that intertwines 2 irreducible representations of my group corresponding to 2 distinct values of r, say, $r$ and $r^{\prime}$:

$$\hat{X}^{r^{\prime}}=\hat{x}-i(r^{\prime}-1)\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial y}=\hat{U}\hat{X}^{r}\hat{U}^{-1}=\hat{U}\left[\hat{x}-i(r-1)\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right]\hat{U}^{-1},\\
\hat{Y}^{r^{\prime}}=\hat{y}-ir^{\prime}\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\hat{U}\hat{Y}^{r}\hat{U}^{-1}=\hat{U}\left[\hat{y}-ir\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right]\hat{U}^{-1},\\
\hat{U}\hat{p}_{x}\hat{U}^{-1}=\hat{p}_{x},\\
\hat{U}\hat{p}_{y}\hat{U}^{-1}=\hat{p}_{y}.$$

N.B.: Here, $\hat{x}$, and $\hat{y}$ are the 2 multiplication operators on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2},dxdy)$:
$$(\hat{x}\psi)(x,y)=x\psi(x,y),\\
(\hat{y}\psi)(x,y)=y\psi(x,y),$$
for a given $\psi\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2},dxdy)$.

Motivation: I want to find the unitary operator $\hat{U}$ in the form $$\hat{U}=e^{i\hat{T}(r,r^{\prime})},$$ where $\hat{T}(r,r^{\prime})$ will be some possibly unbounded self adjoint operator densely defined on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2},dxdy)$. It will then allow me to write a star exponential of some some smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that can be treated as noncommutative U(1) elements.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question but you have a nilpotent group with 6 generators $X,Y,A,B,Z,Z'$ with relations $[X,Y]=Z$ and $[X,A]=[Y,B]=Z'$. You can use Kirillov orbit method to know which orbits your representation correspond to. If your two representations for $r,r'$ different correspond to different orbits then there is no such unitary map. If they correspond to same orbit then try to find a unitary with the representation constructed by Kirillov.

Comment: You didn’t understand the setup. It’s a 7 dimensional nilpotent Lie group with a 3 dimensional centre. The non central generators are represented by self adjoint operators $\hat{X}^{r}, \hat{Y}^{r},\hat{p}_{x}$ and $\hat{p}_{y}$ as given above. All 3 central generators are mapped to the identity operator on the Hilbert space. The unitary dual of this nilpotent Lie group has been computed in earlier papers. Here r is a gauge parameter and hence representations that are obtained by varying r are all unitarily equivalent and thus correspond to the same coadjoint orbit.

Comment: More on the nilpotent Lie group in question can be found here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.7086.pdf